# PHP DOM - How to retrieve nodeValue and href of a specific element

Tags: php, dom

I have a loop through wich I would like to push the nodeValue and href of the first a element of the first div element. I am new to DOM so I read several posts and came up with the following code. Unfortunately this is not working. Hope someone can help me through with that. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

Here below the html structure of $value (see loop below to understand what is $value)

```
    <body>
        <div>
           <a href="myhreflink">this is my target</a>
           <a href="somehref">sometext</a>
        </div>

        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </body>
```

Here below my loop:

```
 myarray = array();  
 /* $content is a DOMNodeList Object and $value is a DOMElement Object */

foreach ($content as $value){

    $firstDiv = $value->getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    $firstA = $firstDiv->getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

    $val = $firstA->nodeValue;
    $link = $firstA->getAttribute('href');

    array_push($myarray, array('val'=>$val, 'href'=>$link));    
}
```

-> Here below the full code----------

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysql_set_charset('utf8'); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

$liste = array();


    $url = 'myurl';
    $path = 'mypath'; 
    $titres = print_url_data($url, $path);

    foreach($titres as $value){
        array_push($liste, $value);
    }




// -> functions ------------------------------------------------------------

function print_url_data($url, $path){
    $content = get_url_data($url, $path);
    $tableau = array();
    foreach ($content as $value){

        $firstDiv = $value->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
        $firstA = $firstDiv->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);

        $val = $firstA->nodeValue;
        $link = $firstA->getAttribute('href');

        array_push($myarray, array('val'=>$val, 'href'=>$link));  
    }
    return $tableau;
}

function get_url_data($url, $path){
    $xml_content = get_url($url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($xml_content);
    $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
    $content_title = $xpath->query($path);
    return $content_title;
}

function get_url($url){

    $curl = curl_init();

    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, '[url=http://www.google.com]http://www.google.com[/url]');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);


    $html = curl_exec($curl); 
    curl_close($curl);
    return $html; 
}

?>
```

Comment: Remove the `@` from `@$dom->loadHTML()` if that is failing, everything else will fail but you won't know it because you suppressed the error!

Comment: this is not causing any error. I used that function a lot. So  can say that this is not a potential source for the problem...

Comment: still, either `$value` may not contain what it is supposed to. For example, it might be a plain string instead of a DOMNode.

Comment: If you look the first picture of my post, this what is $value. I used echo $value->c14N(false,true); to "echo it out'

Answer (score 1):

This type of array dereferencing is not valid in PHP prior to the brand new PHP 5.4.

```
// Can't do this unless running PHP5.4 (which seems unlikely)
// Actually without a way to test, I'm not sure that DOMDocument would even
// suppor this under PHP5.4
$firstDiv = $value->getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
$firstA = $firstDiv->getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
```

Instead, you need to store and then retrieve the value by index with `item()`.

```
$firstDiv = $value->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
$firstA = $firstDiv->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
```

#### Update

I think I get it now - since `$content` is a NodeList, you don't want to iterate over it in `foreach` instead, call `getElementsByTagName()` on it directly.  By iterating over it, you get individual nodes, rather than node lists, and you can't call `getElementsByTagName()` on individual nodes that I'm aware of.

```
function print_url_data($url, $path){
    $content = get_url_data($url, $path);
    $tableau = array();

    // No need to loop. get nodes directly from $content   
    $firstDiv = $content->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
    $firstA = $firstDiv->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);

    $val = $firstA->nodeValue;
    $link = $firstA->getAttribute('href');

    // this is not going to work since $myarray isn't initialized
    // you might have meant to use $tableau
    array_push($myarray, array('val'=>$val, 'href'=>$link));  

    return $tableau;
}
```

Comment: I just tested it out and unfortunately I still have the error 500 (internal server error). If I remove those line I do not get any errors. But of course nothing is working...

Comment: @Marc You need to check your logs for the actual error. Or turn on errors `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Followed your input and got this error-> 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in /

Comment: @Marc on which call? the first or second? If the first, then `$content` doesn't have the node list you think it does. If the second, then no `div` was found.

Comment: To be more precise i echoed-out my real $value. You can have a look at the top of my post. I added a screencapture...

Comment: @Marc post more code, where `$content` is loaded. Also, `var_dump($value)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking so much time to help me out. So I just edited my post and inputed my full code. So you will see that the idea is to use curl to get a webpage and extract some info from it and push it finally to an array... Thanks again Michael.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. But I tried this : $nodeValue = $value->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue; wich is working.      Do not bother anymore. You spend already too much time helping. I'll keep diging. Thanks a lot again for your inputs... I learned things...

Comment: @Marc inside the loop or without the loop? `$value` doesn't exist without the loop.

Comment: Good luck. Sorry I can't nail it.